# How to update a progressBar inside a ProgressDialog?

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I need to update a **custom** progressBar in a custom layout which is being added to a **ProgressDialog** as a **View**.

Custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <com.android.library.circleprogress.ArcProgress
        android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        custom:arc_progress="5"
        custom:arc_stroke_width="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        custom:arc_bottom_text="Updating..."/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
public static ProgressDialog createProgressDialog(Context mContext, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    try {
        dialog.show();
    } catch (BadTokenException e) {

    }
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, viewGroup);
    // this is the progressBar I need to update 
    ArcProgress arcProgress = (ArcProgress) view.findViewById(R.id.arc_progress);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    return dialog;
}
```

And I am calling this create dialog in a **doInBackground** method from an **AsyncTask**, so I need to update the percentage number to make the bar moves.

```
...
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = Util.createProgressDialog(context, null);
    pDialog.show();
}
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    String file = Util.getMapFiles().get(bean).toLowerCase() + ".txt";
    // this download updates the pDialog.setProgress(percent)
    Integer total = ftpDb.download(bean, Const.DIR_FTP_INICIO, file, pDialog);
    return total;
}
```

Any ideas how I could achieve that? 
With **default ProgressDialog** I can update the percentage bar with no problem.

Comment: Async task inside onProgressUpdate Method you have to use. and do in background call publishprogress method

Comment: Try This---> dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.custom_layout));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an interface inside your AsyncTask, like this:

```
public interface AsyncTaskDelegate{
    public void updateProgress(int progress);
}
```

Then in your AsyncTask constructor you want a reference to this delegate, like this:

```
private AsyncTaskDelegate mDelegate;

public MyAsyncTask(AsyncTaskDelegate del){
   this.mDelegate=del;
}
```

After this, you can override the OnProgressUpdate, like this:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     this.mDelegate(progress[0]);
}
```

then in your doInBackground, whenever you want to update the progress you call the method publishUpdate(someinteger).

Remember to save a reference to your progressbar where you implement the delegate and use the progressbar.setProgress() there.